# How to switch users while developing?

Tags: thinktecture-ident-server, identityserver3

we need the ability to switch users from our client interface while we're in debugging mode.  is there an easy way to do this?  how do we do this with identity server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are in debug mode, you have already been assigned a claims principal, So you might need to create and assign a different principal at debug mode.

Otherwise you can rely on creating test principal at application startup as described here(without using an identity server). http://www.weliwita.com/blog/?p=47